# 100% DIV width is not really 100%

Tags: css, html, scroll, width

When I have a `<div>` with `width: 100%`, it is not really 100%:

```
<div id="div">testtesttesttesttest</div>

...

#div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Now when you resize the window, so there is a horizontal scrollbar, and you scroll to the right, then the background is vanished. How can I remain the background in this case?

Here you can see the problem in action:
http://beta.ovoweb.net/?i=3

Now when you resize the window and scroll to the right, you can't see the background anymore. How to fix this?

Comment: Tried adding `margin: 0;` to the CSS? To the `body` as well as the DIV itself.

Comment: The problem is not with that element, but its parent elements. You need to provide your HTML/CSS. A live link would be best, otherwise a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) would suffice.

Comment: `div` width is 100% by default so it might be the parent!!

Comment: Note to anyone else struggling with this, IN CASE your `div` in question has no content (except for sub-elements with `float: left` or `float: right`, which don't count), setting `width: 100%` (or any other value) has no effect; the `div` must have content for the `width` setting to take effect.  Simply adding one piece of whitespace (`&nbsp;`) works in this situation.  I got bit by this so I thought I'd post a comment, in case!

Comment: @DanNissenbaum , is there a CSS solution to that issue?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The 100% value is 100% of the parent's width or the view port. See the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-width).

Comment: So how do you make a full page body dynamically scale to widen as the browser window widens?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this question and answer.

Answer (score 23):

Width: 100%, is highly affected by its margin and margin and padding of its parent (body in your case). SO, reset them first

Something like

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#div {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/eELdP/)

Comment: padding of parent div was messing me up

Answer (score 5):

add this to css:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 2):

100% is only 100% of the available width, based on the parent container. So if you create a DIV with width 500 pixels, then nest another DIV inside with width 100%, your 100% DIV can expand to a maximum of 500 pixels (not counting any padding or margin so you need to reset them to 0).

Answer (score 2):

This oughta do it (add this line to the very top of your CSS file):

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Works all the time for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the div tag did not take up 100% of its parent tag because the div had a display of "inline."  Changing it to "inline-block" fixed that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the I time add [this bit of code](http://jsfiddle.net/zPLDt/2/) to my css. It should work for you too. Yes, 100% `width` or `height` is always based on the parent container.

**CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#content {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 10%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

​**HTML**

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check if you have this code in the div or it parent:

```
 #div  {
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

or

```
 #div  {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

This cause the width not to be 100% of the page. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have row included in your class then it sometimes causes problems, remove it and add it inside a new div