# How do i get a 100% width div above a fixed width div?

Tags: css, html, width

I have a problem with something that seems very simple.

Here's the deal.

I have a div at the top of my page which takes the whole width. Below that i want to place a div with a fixed width aligned in the center.

Something like this:

```
<div id="top">
        <p>This is the top wrapper</p>
</div>
<div id="middle">
         <p>This is the fix width wrapper</p>
</div>
```

Style will be

```
#top {
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    width: 100%;
    }

#middle {
    width:900px;
    margin:auto;
    height: 300px;
    background:green;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/JeroenGerth/zeZ4k/2/

If the browserwindow is larger than 900 pixel, everything is fine. But there is a problem when your window is smaller than 900 pixels. You get a horizontal scrollbar. That seems logical, since the #middle div is 900 pixels wide. But when you scroll to the right, you can see the top div doesn't fill the entire width of the screen. It only fills the space you can see before you scroll to the right. You can see some white leftover space at the top right corner of the page.

What am i doing wrong or overlook? Do i can't use a fixed width for the #middle div? :-( How do I get the top div fills the entire width when the windows needs a scrollbar?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% DIV width is not really 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344380/100-div-width-is-not-really-100)

Comment: Just make the `min-width: 900px` on the top container??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because the first div takes 100% of the body, witch can be smaller then 900px.

set

```
#top {
height:100px;
background:red;
width: 100%; /*Not needed - this is the default behavior*/
min-width: 900px; /*set this*/
}
```

Comment: Oooh really? I knew it must me that simple.
Now I understand. I misinterpreted the 100% width. Thinking it always fills from edge to edge. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either set `max-width: 900px;` on `#middle` or `min-width: 900px` on `#top`

http://jsfiddle.net/zeZ4k/3/