# css html full width not functioning properly

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    }

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

#nav.active {
background-color:#4CAF50;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
</div></body>
```

I seem to have space on top and I can't get the full width? what is wrong?
No matter what I do I cannot seem to get the full width and the spacing on top removed. Why doesn't the width:100% work properly here?

Comment: I ran into this recently. I can't look to be sure right now, but I think the solution was to add the following CSS: `body {height:100%; width:100%}`

Comment: i dont get what you mean.......

Comment: try to add `body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` to get rid of the spacing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [100% DIV width is not really 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344380/100-div-width-is-not-really-100)

Answer (score 1):

add this to your stylesheet:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED, but how come the width 100% had no effect?

Comment: The body tag must have had a margin on it even though it was not explicitly declared. Because that was the parent and the div is inside the body tag, the white space took precedence over the 100% width.

Comment: You have to always(well most of the time) reset your margins and paddings.. by using `*{ margin : 0; padding: 0; }` that way you never have any extra padding or margin on top of what might be defaulted by browsers. etc.

Comment: @juggggggggggggjjjjjjjjjjjj Don't forget to pick an answer to close this question.

Comment: +1 because you got this in just before me and had a better explanation. I feel like you deserve the rep in case your answer never gets selected.

Comment: @Lexi +1 for you too - I didn't add the explanation myself...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a style to the body tag.

```
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

That did the trick for me in Firefox.

Comment: This is working in Chrome and the same thing as @Johannes