# Bottom div won't stretch fully

Tags: html, css

```css
.bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:33px;
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

p.disclaimer {
    color:white;
    text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 0.5px,   #000 0px 0px 0.5px,   #000 0px 0px 0.5px,
                 #000 0px 0px 0.5px,   #000 0px 0px 0.5px,   #000 0px 0px 0.5px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
   <div class="bottom-bar">
        <p class="disclaimer">John V 2015. No copyright infringement intended. <a href="mailto:example@example.com">Contact</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Div that won't stretch]

Hi. My bottom `div` refuses to stretch all the way to the left. It's just in the bottom of the `body` tag, and neither that nor the `html` tag has no particular styling (except for a stretched background).

Ideas?

P.s! I know the "No copyright infringement intended" is useless.

Comment: Please create a working fiddle where we can see the problem directly.

Comment: I agree, it's likely an issue caused by a parent element and we need to see everything to properly help you.

Comment: The default `body` tag has a small margin. Set `body { margin: 0; }` to fix it.

Comment: Yes please create a fiddle.

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister Thanks. Can you leave it as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css html full width not functioning properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406201/css-html-full-width-not-functioning-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` tag has a small default margin - you can unset it with

```
body { margin: 0 }
```

Answer (score 3):

`.bottom-bar { left: 0; right: 0;}`

Comment: This will fix your problem for you.